# Understanding a javascript code from website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand how a webpage works. When you click a button, they call a function from javascript, with some arguments, just like this `<a href="javascript:ShowListing('24343434', 22, '2', '434331')" class="btn">`. The function (in an external .js) looks like this:

```
function ShowListing(id1,id2,id3,id4) {
somecode here
Dialog.Show( id1, assets[id2][id3][id4] );
}
```

My question is, what's assets? I looked for the declaration of the variable in all the scripts and I couldn't find it. Maybe it's defined in a .php?
Is there any way of knowing the value it has given some specific [ids]?
Thanks!

Comment: View source . (ctrl+u). Also check all js file included ..(search for ".js" in source page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, what's assets?

A variable containing an object of some sort. We can't tell any more than that from the code you've supplied.

> I looked for the declaration of the variable in all the scripts and I couldn't find it. Maybe it's defined in a .php?

It has to be defined by client side JavaScript (unless it is a browser built-in which I don't recognise, but seems highly unlikely given the context it is used in). That JS could be in a .php file.

> Is there any way of knowing the value it has given some specific [ids]?

Just about every modern browser has a Developer Tools feature.

Developer Tools come with a JavaScript debugger that lets you set breakpoints.

Set a breakpoint to that line and then you can examine the variables in it using the debugger.

Search terms such as [how to use the chrome developer tools debugger](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+use+the+chrome+developer+tools+debugger) will help you learn to use those tools for your browser.

Comment: Yes, it's an object. I'll try to find where it's first declared with this tools. Thanks

Comment: Sir i want to know this myself `Just about every modern browser has a Developer Tools feature.` IE has dev tool like chrome as well?that can debug?Because i need to do some debugging in ID because some of my script works well in other browsers only IE has problem

Comment: @guradio — https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+use+the+Internet+Explorer+developer+tools+debugger

Answer (score 1):

First hit F12 if you're on firefox (i think the same goes for chrome) the console panel should be visible, then add the console.log() and refresh the page to see what is asset use

```
console.log(assets);
```

the same goes for the other ids and the value of each array in `assets`

Comment: this will print a string name `assets`

Comment: After editing, that will only work if `assets` is a global variable.

Comment: It does print the object, thanks, i'll try to keep on going from that! I didn't know about the Console functionality in chrome. Is there any way of knowing where was this object declared?

Comment: to know where it was declared, you need some debugging tools I guess